# How can I define new places for setf?

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros, common-lisp

**Q:** how do I teach `setf` about new places it can set?

In common lisp, one uses the
macro [`defsetf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defset.htm) to tell
`setf` about new places it can set.

In elisp, that macro exists in in the `cl` library, but, as far as
I can tell, has not been ported into the updated `cl-lib` library.
However,
[we're not supposed to use the old `cl` library:](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/cl.html)

> Since the old `cl.el` does not use a clean namespace, Emacs has a
>   policy that packages distributed with Emacs must not load `cl` at
>   run time. (It is ok for them to load `cl` at compile time, with
>   `eval-when-compile`, and use the macros it provides.) There is no
>   such restriction on the use of `cl-lib`. New code should use
>   `cl-lib` rather than `cl`.

Does `defsetf` (or a substitute) exist somewhere else?  How else
should I tell `setf` about new places?

Comment: The docstring for `defsetf` in `cl.el` equates different forms of `defsetf` with `gv-define-simple-setter` and `gv-define-setter`, which are in turn described as easy-to-use substitutes for `gv-define-expander`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where does it say that you're not supposed to use library `cl.el`? That would be silly (IMHO). The text you quote says that *code **distributed with GNU Emacs** must not load `cl` at runtime.* That does not say that **you** should not use `cl.el` (at runtime or any other time).

Some people don't want to *load* all of `cl.el` at runtime. That's one reason `cl-lib.el` was created: as a *subset* of `cl.el`. (Another reason was to provide the prefix `cl-` more systematically, as mentioned in the text you quote.)

But `defsetf` is a **macro**. You generally *do not need a macro at runtime*. You typically need it only at byte-compile time.

This is all you need: **`(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))`**.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know what the policy is about using `cl` with packages that might be distributed via elpa or melpa?  And do you happen to know if the rest of `cl` is going to get ported into something like `cl-lib` (re: "New code should use `cl-lib` rather than `cl`")?

Comment: Hi Dan. No, I really don't know these things. Your best bet is to ask emacs-devel@gnu.org. 
As many of my libraries try to support multiple Emacs releases, including some that predate `cl-lib.el`, I generally avoid using CL functions in my code, but I use CL macros and use `eval-when-compile` to load their definitions at byte-compile time.

Answer (score 5):

Drew's answer is correct, but it should also be mentioned that the reason `cl-lib` doesn't include a `cl-defsetf` (or `cl-setf`) is because the `setf` machinery has been moved to `gv.el`.  The docstring of `defsetf` suggests `gv-define-simple-setter` and `gv-define-setter` as alternatives.